# Tkinter Messagebox - Save Messagebox answers (eg. Does user pick 'Yes 'or 'No')

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

So I'm writing an app in Python 3.6, but I can't seem to find an answer on how to get the value of a messagebox answer (Yes or No).

```
fileSavedExit = True
def msgbox1():
    if fileSavedExit == True:
        root.destroy()  
    if fileSavedExit == False:
        messagebox.askyesno('Save File ?','Do you want to save the file first?')
```

Something like that. I'm looking for code that would save the answer (`'Yes'` or `'No'`). Would be thankful if anyone would help me. :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`askyesno` returns `True` if the answer was `"Yes"` and `False` if the answer was `"No"`. You can simply filter it with `if/else`.

## Example

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as tkmb


def ask():
    response = tkmb.askyesno("Messagebox Title", "Is this it?")
    global button
    if response:    # If the answer was "Yes" response is True
        button['text'] = "Yes"
    else:           # If the answer was "No" response is False
        button['text'] = "No"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Ask...", command=ask)
    button.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: @SzymonPokrywka No problem. See [tkinter tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tkinter/info) for more resources.